# Rails 4 parse XML to table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I had XML file like http://www.heureka.cz/direct/xml-export/shops/heureka-sekce.xml. I'm unable to change it because it is not mine. It's just parsing from another website.

Here's XML (with structure):

```
<HEUREKA>
  <CATEGORY>
    <CATEGORY_ID>971</CATEGORY_ID>
    <CATEGORY_NAME>Auto-moto</CATEGORY_NAME>
    <CATEGORY>
      <CATEGORY_ID>881</CATEGORY_ID>
      <CATEGORY_NAME>Alkohol testery</CATEGORY_NAME>
      <CATEGORY_FULLNAME>Heureka.cz | Auto-moto | Alkohol testery</CATEGORY_FULLNAME>
    </CATEGORY>
  </CATEGORY>
</HEUREKA>
```

Thanks to all commenting  here is  final Code

```
def heureka
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://www.heureka.cz/direct/xml-export/shops/heureka-sekce.xml"))

doc.xpath("//CATEGORY[CATEGORY_FULLNAME]").each do |node|
record = Heureka.where("name" => node.css('CATEGORY_NAME').inner_text).first_or_initialize
record.fullname=node.xpath('CATEGORY_FULLNAME').inner_text
record.name=node.xpath('CATEGORY_NAME').inner_text                                                                                         
record.save unless record.fullname.blank?                                                                                                  
end                                                                                                                                        
end
```

Comment: Please, show what do you want to get, and how it is working now. And the document has a few levels of categories, you should check it in each loop.

Comment: @zishe i am expect my code traverse every level and if CATEGORY_FULLNAME present then store it to DB .

Answer (score 6):

Using nokogiri in this place seems a litte oversized. You can do this with plain ruby:

```
require 'net/http'
xml_content = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse('http://www.heureka.cz/direct/xml-export/shops/heureka-sekce.xml'))
data = Hash.from_xml(xml_content)
```

Then your able to access the data as a hash object.

Comment: Hi i am sorry but i am newbie can you tell me how to save only categories with filled  <CATEGORY_FULLNAME>

Answer (score 1):

If we indent your XML you will see the problem:

```
<HEUREKA>
  <CATEGORY>
    <CATEGORY_ID>971</CATEGORY_ID>
    <CATEGORY_NAME>Auto-moto</CATEGORY_NAME>
    <CATEGORY>
      <CATEGORY_ID>881</CATEGORY_ID>
      <CATEGORY_NAME>Alkohol testery</CATEGORY_NAME>
      <CATEGORY_FULLNAME>Heureka.cz | Auto-moto | Alkohol testery</CATEGORY_FULLNAME>
    </CATEGORY>
  </CATEGORY>
</HEUREKA>
```

The second category node is *inside* the first category node, so it also its child. Because of this `children.css('CATEGORY_NAME').inner_text` will return both names concatenated (`Auto-motoAlkohol testery`) for the first node, and the last one will have the expected data - (`Alkohol testery`).

Fix your XML:

```
<HEUREKA>
  <CATEGORY>
    <CATEGORY_ID>971</CATEGORY_ID>
    <CATEGORY_NAME>Auto-moto</CATEGORY_NAME>
  </CATEGORY>
  <CATEGORY>
    <CATEGORY_ID>881</CATEGORY_ID>
    <CATEGORY_NAME>Alkohol testery</CATEGORY_NAME>
    <CATEGORY_FULLNAME>Heureka.cz | Auto-moto | Alkohol testery</CATEGORY_FULLNAME>
  </CATEGORY>
</HEUREKA>
```

And try again...

---

**Update**

If you can't change the XML, you can use `XPATH` instead of `CSS`, as its default behavior is to find the *immediate* children, rather than all the children (deep children):

```
def heurekacat
  require 'open-uri'
  require 'nokogiri'
  doc = Nokogiri::XML(open("http://www.heureka.cz/direct/xml-export/shops/heureka-sekce.xml"))
  doc.css("CATEGORY").each do |node|
    record = HeurekaCat.where("name" => children.xpath('CATEGORY_NAME').inner_text).first_or_initialize
    record.category=node.xpath('CATEGORY_FULLNAME').inner_text
    record.name=node.xpath('CATEGORY_NAME').inner_text
    record.save
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi am unable to correct XML , i am had to find solution for nested categories and save only ones which saves only categories with filled<CATEGORY_FULLNAME>

Comment: @TomasKrmela - added a solution for a case where you can't fix the XML

Comment: how to save to db only if CATEGORY_FULLNAME is presented at node

Comment: `record.save unless record.category.blank?`

Comment: Thanks Uri Agassi for solving my issue

Comment: Hi well issues is not yet fixed cause xml is multi level it is not only two levels but tree of nested categories likes <category><category><category></category></category></category>

Comment: and Active Record puts all included values   in   Heureka Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  `heurekas`.* FROM `heurekas`  WHERE `heurekas`.`name` = 'Vodní sportyOblečení a obuvKrátké oblekyMokré oblekyNeoprénové botyNeoprenové rukaviceNeoprényPolosuché oblekyPotapěčské kapuce

Comment: it is all included columns in child

Comment: how to avoid to include all collums  like at example one comment previous

Comment: @TomasKrmela Sorry, I had a typo in the `HeurekaCat.where(` line - it should be `xpath`, not `css`...

Comment: i am updated whole question to lastest code but elements we have severale levels of <CATEGORY> i wish to save only filled  CATEGORY_FULLNAME>

Comment: @TomasKrmela your update does not include my fix in the `HeurekaCat.where(` line

Answer (score 0):

Simply change one line:

```
doc.css("CATEGORY").each do |node|
```

to the following:

```
doc.css("CATEGORY:has(CATEGORY_FULLNAME)").each do |node|
```

This selects only `CATEGORY` elements containing a `CATEGORY_FULLNAME` subelement.

As an alternative, the equivalent XPath:

```
doc.xpath("//CATEGORY[CATEGORY_FULLNAME]").each do |node|
```